# Select or deselect item in array and increase or decrease its value react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically i want to select an emoji from an array which contains objects (id, name, count) and if i select an item on the array i want to increase its value and if i deselct it i want to decrease its value

for now i've done this which basically increase the value of an item in the array, please help me, thanks.

this is the array

```
const [emojisArr, setEmojisArr] = React.useState([
    {
      name: 'like',
      emoji: '',
      count: 11,
    },
    {
      name: 'heart',
      emoji: '❤️',
      count: 21,
    },
    {
      name: 'joy',
      emoji: '',
      count: 31,
    },
    {
      name: 'fire',
      emoji: '',
      count: 34,
    },
    {
      name: 'star',
      emoji: '',
      count: 5,
    },
  ]);
```

and this is the function when i click on the button

```
const likePost = item => {
 const index = emojisArr.findIndex(emoji => emoji.name === item);
 emojisArr[index].count += 1;
 setEmojisArr(old => [...old]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this code see below. you can pass action (selected/deselected) as string. so, it can increment/decrement count on the behalf of action.

```
const post = (item, action) => {
    const newState = emojisArr.map((emoji) => {
      if (emoji.name === item) {
        return {
          ...emoji,
          count: action === "selected" ? emoji.count + 1 : emoji.count - 1
        };
      }
      return emoji;
    });
    setEmojisArr(newState);
  };
```

Comment: This works, but how can i do to deselect the selected item?

Comment: I've updated the answer, If it's helpful please mark as accepted answer So, others knows it has been resolved. Thanks :)